# Leaflet shapes (circle, polygon) unclickable after dragging map

Tags: javascript, firefox, leaflet

I recently upgraded to Leaflet 1.3.4. I drew a circle and a polygon on the map. I made them interactive so that I get a different mouse pointer when I move my mouse over them--all well and good, behaving as expected.

Then, I dragged the map a little to the left and moved my mouse back to my shape. To my surprise, the pointer did not change as it had previously. It was as if there wasn't an interactive shape there at all, according to the mouse cursor. I dragged my mouse across the shape a little more, and suddenly, I got the correct (interactive) cursor again.

After more experimentation, it's as if there's an invisible "window" that gets created around the shapes on the map. The window does not move when you drag the map; only the shapes do. The shapes only receive mouse events if they are inside that window. I could confirm this by moving the map bit by bit, and the shapes would slowly lose their "interactive" surface area.

Sorry that's a bit of a long explanation, but it's a really weird problem. If I can clarify this at all, please leave me a comment and I'll do my best.

I looked through Stack questions and current Leaflet issues and didn't see anything related to this. Why would my map and shapes behave in this way, and how can I fix it? I'd appreciate any insight or ideas.

Edit: I'm using Firefox version 60.1.

Edit 2: I was able to reproduce this **using Firefox 60** and this code:

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
 layers: [
  new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  })
 ],
 center: [0, 0],
 zoom: 0
});

var latlngs = [[37, -109.05],[41, -109.03],[41, -102.05],[37, -102.04]];
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
html, body, #leaflet {
 height: 100%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Leaflet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="leaflet"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Drag the map to the left, right, up, down, etc, and you won't get a mouseover cursor change for the shape.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could set up the example using something like http://leafletjs.com/edit.html.

Comment: So, I did try to reproduce it that way (using Chrome) and couldn't, so I didn't include it. I'll see if it happens with Firefox.

Comment: After consistently reproducing with Firefox 60, I'm going to submit an issue on Leaflet's github page.

Comment: That is a [known issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5773) with Firefox only, and it is not specific to Leaflet. Unfortunately we have not investigated far enough to determine exactly what could be the root cause.

Comment: Thanks, @ghybs, that's helpful--glad to know I'm not the only one. I'll use a Canvas renderer for now.